# Need to grant two users to an AIX server to just one folder

Tags: ssh, permissions, aix

Ok, in our environment, most users (including myself as one of the unix admins) don't actually have admin rights directly on the aix servers.  We login to a front unix server as ourselves without root access.  Then we run a command that logs us in as the actual root user but everything we do is logged to a text file, so if we really screw something up, there are logs to point fingers at who did it.  I can't login directly to the unix servers.  I don't have access.  I have to login to the logging server, then ssh to the server as direct root.

Well, I have a request right now that two users that know absolutely nothing about how to navigate a unix command prompt needs access to some log files 3 folders deep.

We're going to make it so they're going to log directly into the unix box with the log files, so they don't go through the server that logs all their command history.  But our plan is to create them as basic users with no administrative access.  Then they're actually going to access the files using a GUI utility to just copy and paste the files to their Windows machines.

The permissions on this server without making any modifications look like this already...

parent folder `drwxrwxrwx`

sub folder `drwxrwxr-x`

log folder `drwxr-xr-x`

log files `-rw-rw-r--`

So, if I create two users on the box and make them part of no security groups, they should already be able to navigate down to the folder no problem because everyone has read access down to the log files.

But, what we want is something super simple for these two non-unix experienced users.  I've been working this job as a unix admin for about 3 months.  I've taken a lot of unix classes but most of my professional experience is in Windows servers.  I know in a Windows environment, I'd just share out the logs folder.  The user, if wanted to experiment, might notice they could access the parent folder, but probably wouldn't know enough to try it.

Is there a way in an AIX unix environment to just somehow share the logs folder out so the users don't have to drill down to the logs folder and possibly get lost or access something they shouldn't access?  I'm not changing the permissions.  I've been working for this company for 3 months and a multi-million dollar enterprise doesn't like me telling them what they've been doing for the last 20 years is wrong and they should change it.  So, I have to make work what they already have in place.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be needlessly complicating things. Personally, I would just do one of

1. Email the files to the users. You're talking about a one-time thing, involving two users and some text files. Just send two emails and your job is done.
2. Copy the files yourself to somewhere where the users already have access. Since they won't ever need to go back to your Unix system, setting up something to allow them to do so seems overkill.

Now, if you really really want to, you can:

1. Export the log folder to their machines using the `smb` protocol, [samba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_%28software%29) for example. That way, the "share" will be accessible just like any other Windows shared folder.
2. Serve the log files through an HTTP server if one is running on the machines.
3. If you insist on having them access the Unix server, just link the log files to their home directories:

   ```
   ln -s /path/to/logfile/folder ~username/logfiles
   ```

   That way, when they log in, the files will already be right there in their `$HOME`.
4. Allow them to log in and add them to a special group which owns the log files and give that group access to the files in question. Seriously though, don't. It's more complicated and time consuming and completely unnecessary.
5. As JennyD suggests, if the files change regularly, you can set up a [cronjob](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html) that regularly copies the files to a place where the users have access.

Comment: 5. Run a cron job that copies the files to a box that can smbmount a network share that they can then access from their windows boxes.

Comment: I like the ln -s idea.  I don't have the luxary of doing the e-mail thing or copying them elsewhere.  I think, from the sound of it that this is going to be more than a one time thing.  But I'm just the engineer.  The situation filtered down to me saying they need access to it and make a solution that works so they can grab  them when they need them.  Here's our 10,000 foot view of how we want it to work.  Now it's your job to make it happen.